# How to make a button create a label and shortly after that hide in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

My code:

```py
def Click():
    global output
    output = StringVar()
    output = random.randint(1, 6)   
    global outputL
    outputL = Label(root, text = f"The number is... {output}")
    outputL.pack()
    output = 0
```

How do I make it hide the label after that?

Comment: have you checked out the `after` method? the easiest is to simply use `help(Tk.after)` in the console or wherever (just first import `Tk`); also in case you are doing that, don't use `*` when importing, and that comment is not really helpful, you can just delete it, if you want to add some more info to the question you can [edit] it, otherwise, it may get lost in the comments

Comment: @Matiiss You can flag comments that are no longer needed

Comment: The `output = StringVar()` line is useless; you overwrite it immediately afterward.  You are using it as a normal variable, so you wouldn't need the `StringVar` anyway.

Comment: @wjandrea always thought flagging was for serious problems and didn't consider that, thank you, now will try doing that when appropriate (flag for no longer needed comments in such cases)

Answer (score 0):

Use after method and config method

(TIP) Don't create a widgets(Labels, Buttons, etc...) inside a function. Use config method to update your widgets

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()

def Remove_Output():
    outputL.pack_forget()

def click():
    global output
    output = StringVar()
    output = random.randint(1, 6)
    outputL.config(text=f"The number is... {output}")
    outputL.pack()
    output = 0  
    root.after(1000, Remove_Output)

btn = Button(root, text="Click",command=click)
btn.pack()

outputL = Label(root, text = "")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and the tip!